# How to install python on macos into /usr/bin folder?

Tags: python, macos

I need a specific version of python to fit into the `/usr/bin` directory on my Mac to satisfy a bunch of tools that internally assume that location. These tools normally run on linux. I'm trying to create an environment on my Mac to develop on for tools that don't need to run on linux. The linux environments are setup using the command

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends python3.6-dev
```

which appears to install by default into `/usr/bin` as a direct binary executable:

```bash
$ ls -la /usr/bin | grep python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           23 Dec 24  2018 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4555968 Dec 24  2018 python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           33 Dec 24  2018 python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4555968 Dec 24  2018 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Dec 24  2018 python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Dec 24  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         3204 Dec 24  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
```

### Python.org Mac Installer

I tried running the [mac installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/) which appears to create some stuff in my applications folder

```
$ tree -L 1 /Applications/Python\ 3.6/
/Applications/Python\ 3.6/
├── IDLE.app
├── Icon\r
├── Install\ Certificates.command
├── License.rtf
├── Python\ Documentation.html -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/English.lproj/Documentation/index.html
├── Python\ Launcher.app
├── ReadMe.rtf
└── Update\ Shell\ Profile.command
```

While also adding a route to this python on my PATH

```
$ which python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

There's a bit of commentary discussing the specific flavor of mac and python installs at the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#getting-and-installing-macpython but it doesn't clue me into how I can install into something other than *Applications*.

### Symlink Workaround Attempt

I tried a workaround to create a symbolic link in my `/usr/bin` folder with sudo but I just get an `Operation not permitted`, which is apparently out of bounds by  [Apple's System Integrity Protection](https://superuser.com/questions/1168773/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-usr-bin-on-a-mac).

```bash
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6    /usr/bin/python3.6
ln: /usr/bin/python3.6: Operation not permitted
```

Maybe I can build from source and publish directly to /usr/bin?

Comment: Why not just symlink it? `/usr/bin` is not recommended as anything you put there could get wiped out with an update of `macOS`.

Comment: Why do you want/need to? Speaking as someone who's worn an OS-vendor hat in the past (and wears an embedded-device-vendor hat now), your OS vendor ensuring that everything they distribute can't have its behavior modified from what's tested and known to work is to your benefit; keeping user-installed software on the PATH but *outside* vendor-controlled directory trees means vendor-shipped software continues to work as it was originally written, and that you have control over whether you're running your custom software stack (by changing the PATH) in a given context, or not.

Comment: If the tools are assuming a specific version of Python in a specific place, even on Linux, they are wrong. They should be using `/usr/bin/env python` which will work everywhere.

Comment: Incidentally, my favorite package manager (even on MacOS) is [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/); each piece of software gets installed under its own hash-addressed `/nix/store` directory, so you can have programs that would normally conflict with each other installed alongside, and which subset is in-use can very per session/program/etc.

Comment: ...anyhow, MacOS Catalina's use of an immutable root filesystem is following a trend that arguably went mainstream with ChromeOS's use of `dm_verity`; from a product-security perspective, that trend is a *great* one.

Comment: Please _don't_. You're going to break your OS.

Comment: @l'L'l symlink's are prohibited, the attempt is covered in the question above, I added some section breaks to better format with.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wish it was just shebangs, but it's actually hardcoded and baked into python subprocess calls and probably other system calls and statements in shell scripts across a collection of tools in different languages.

Comment: @Chris that's a good concern; I was hoping to take care to install first to another folder and look at what name conflicts might arise with the system python. I was going to force the 3.6 suffix if it wasn't already there and hope things still work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman actually, I'm going to get the tools to be fixed to use the generalized `env` approach. There's actually more instances of that in the codebase than the hardcoded path. Should make the argument go a lot smoother.